# Looking for Windows VPS with full admin rights

Tags: vps, virtualhost

I am looking for a Windows VPS provider that will allow me to install any applications that I want on it.  I tried the GoDaddy VPS plan, but it wouldn't let me install the windows updates that were required for SQL 2008.  Do I need to go up to full dedicated or is there a provider that can give me full admin control?

Comment: Product and service recommendations, including service recon, are off topic per the updated [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Comment: Amazon EC2. Windows 2008 R2 instance. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most VPS providers will give you full control (the "P" stands for "Private", it's yours), but if they are based on Virtuozzo then you will not be able to install updates or install device drivers.

You cannot install device drivers because Virtuozzo is not hardware virtualisation, rather it is software virtualisation. If you download a Windows update you run the risk of it breaking the virtualisation.

You cannot install device drivers for the same reason, you might do something funny in the kernel that will break virtualisation. This might not be a problem for you, but if you want to run the VPS as a VPN endpoint with a single hardware NIC (extranet), you will most often end up installing a software NIC as the intranet. My favourite is the Microsoft Loopback Adapter. Despite being signed, Virtuozzo won't run it.

Virtuozzo also does some funny things with VPN/SSL acceleration that prevents the .NET Framework 3.5 from installing and the VPN services for Windows Server 2008 from starting.

You can get around the latter by enabling VPN support on the host but this is a ticket to support. For me, they didn't understand the limitations of their own product and thought I wanted help installing a VPN.

If you can live with the limitations of Virtuozzo (there are a few), I would suggest KickAssVPS. If you want hardware level virtualisation, try Hyper V Mart.

If you look around at WebHostingTalk, Hyper V Mart had some nice lifetime 25% off vouchers floating around.

Hyper V Mart also have a sister site, Database Mart. If you're running the VPS only as a SQL server you may find it cheaper to buy SQL server hosting.

Comment: Where Virtuozzo is concerned, the "P" in "VPS" stands for "Pseudo".

Comment: That's perfect thanks!  I signed up for hyper-v mart, that sounds a lot better then the virtuozzo solutions out there.  I didn't think I was asking for a lot to be able to install SQL Sever 2008, but its good to know what the limitations are.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'm surprised that there are Windows VPS providers that *don't* give you full control.  I know [Anchor Systems](http://www.anchor.com.au/vps/virtual-private-server.py) give you full control over your Windows VPS (disclaimer: I know this because I work there).  I would imagine that most providers do the same, though; a quick question to the sales department should elicit an appropriate answer.

Comment: Womble man you seem to work everywhere. Didn't you say the other day you worked for a registrar as well?

Comment: ZOMG, a company that does more than one thing!  HOW IS THAT POSSIBLE?!?!?!?!!!?!?!?!?!?!?!!!111!!!!one!!!!eleventy!!!  See https://www.anchor.com.au/domain-name-registration/domain_order.py, specifically, "Anchor is an accredited Australian domain name registrar".  Now, back under your bridge.